# Maven fails to run the file (LifecycleExecutionException)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

When I try to run file in Netbeans maven project it fails with following trace:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project Geodesy_Testing: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project Geodesy_Testing: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
    ... 21 more
```

I have no compiler erros or warning in code.

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean[] df = Utils.toBinary(17, 5);
    boolean[] ca = Utils.toBinary(3, 3);
    boolean[] icao = Utils.toBinary(0x1ab8, 24);

    boolean[] result = Utils.concatArrays(df, ca, icao); // *

    byte[] frame = Utils.booleansToBytes(result); // *

    System.out.println(Utils.bytesToString(frame));
}
```

When I comment out lines with * it runs fine.

Here is implementation of those methods:

```
public static byte[] booleansToBytes(boolean[] boolArr) {
    if (boolArr.length % 8 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Boolean array size must be multiple of 8!");
    }
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[boolArr.length / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.length; i++) {
        byteArr[i] = boolsToByte(boolArr, 8 * i);
    }
    return byteArr;
}

public static boolean[] concatArrays(boolean[]... arrays) {
    boolean[] result = null;
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            result = Arrays.copyOf(arrays[i], arrays[i].length);
        } else {
            System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, result, offset, arrays[i].length);
        }
        offset += arrays[i].length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Forgot to turn the -X off & didn't noticed the more inportant trace.